# Merging animated Gif into background image

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to merge an animated gif into a static jpeg as a background, this is being generated by html canvas and a file upload that the user uploads. I had it working great with imagemagick command line

```
exec("convert ".$_paths['images_dir'].$fname.".gif  \( gif/cleared_dance".$dance.".gif -resize '80%' -repage 0x0-10+$imgHeight\! \) -coalesce -delete 0 -deconstruct -loop 0 ".$_paths['images_dir'].$fname.".gif");
```

this was taking about 15~ seconds to process which was acceptable, but then I found out I can't use the exec command and must use Imagick API, I was eventually able to recreate the process using the following code:

```
$data = $_POST["imgData"]; 
$dance = $_POST["dancer"]+1;
$spriteLeft = $_POST['left'];
$spriteTop = $_POST['top'];
$scale = $_POST['scale'];
$canvas = new Imagick();
$data = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,", "",$data); 
$data = base64_decode($data);
$canvas->readImageBlob($data);

$fname = 'tmp_'.uniqid();
$gif = new Imagick();
$gif->readImage('gif/cleared_dance'.$dance.'.gif');
do {
  $canvas->addImage($gif);
} while ($gif->nextImage());

foreach($canvas as $frame){
   if($frame->getIteratorIndex() != 0){
      $page = $frame->getImagePage();
      $frame->setImagePage(200,200,$page['x']+$spriteLeft,$page['y']+$spriteTop);
   }
}
```

This code takes about 5 seconds which is great but their is a blank frame in the gif when it loops that was super annoying so i added this after:

```
$canvas->setIteratorIndex(0);
$canvas->removeImage();
$canvas = $canvas->deconstructImages();
$canvas->writeImages('tmp/'.$fname.'.gif', true);
```

This takes out the blank frame, but adds about 20 - 30 seconds of processing. Am I doing something wrong, I've played around a good bit with the order of the code and trying different approaches. Is there a way to get the processing time back under 20 seconds like it was with the command line?

Comment: How about giving us an input image and the "cleared_dance" image and an output image so that we can see what we are talking about and experiment a little? Failing that, you might get some benefit from converting "cleared_dance" to IM's MIF format. A little more of your code may also be useful.

Comment: I updated the code to to reflect everything,
here is an example of a processed image with a blank frame it takes about 5 seconds to generate:
http://s16.postimg.org/s0x2b17cl/tmp_54b971d00b8bf.gif
and this took > 20 seconds: 
http://s30.postimg.org/cfcw1uqkh/tmp_54b9725b99690.gif

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite odd. Why are you setting the format of the Imagick object that is going to contain an animated gif to JPG? Why are you fiddling with the image page *after* you composited the image?

I'm pretty sure you want your code to look a lot more like

```
$static = new Imagick();
//$static->readImage("./testFile.png");
$inputGif->readImageBlob($data);

$inputGif = new Imagick();
//$inputGif->readImage('./testGif.gif');
$inputGif->readImage('gif/cleared_dance'.$dance.'.gif');

$gifFrames = $inputGif->coalesceImages();

$outputGif = new Imagick();
$outputGif->setFormat('gif');

foreach ($gifFrames as $gifFrame) {
    $frame = clone $static;
    $frame->compositeimage(
        $gifFrame,
        Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER,  // or maybe \Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP,
        0, 0 // Set the offset here if you don't want the gif in the top left corner.
    );

    $outputGif->addImage($frame);
}

$outputGif->setImageIterations(0); //loop forever
$outputGif->deconstructImages();
$outputGif->writeImages("./outso.gif", true);
```

Comment: Did you mean to write $static->readImageBlob($data);?                 

Well initially I wanted to take the canvas dataURI that was being sent and convert it to JPEG so I could compress it thinking that would decrease the file size of the overall image, but actually I took that out, and it shaved off the 10 extra seconds of processing time. I will try this code and see if its more efficient. Like I said I'm new to imagemagick, was trying to recreate the order of events in the exec command i was using

Comment: I tried this method, and it was 40 seconds to process compared to 15~ the way I had it

Comment: Can you provide some example images for people to use?